# Output multiple child record ids to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been searching for a way to get multiple child records to one row with multiple columns containing the GUID of each record...

Here is what the table looks like:  
StudentParentID   StudentID   ParentID  
1                 1           1  
2                 1           2  
3                 1           3  
4                 2           4  
5                 2           5  
  
What I'd like is a result set like:  
  
StudentID     ParentID1        ParentID2         ParentID3  
1             1                2                 3  
2             4                5                 (null)  
  
I am using SQL Server 2008.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using pivot and rank:

```
select StudentID, [1] as P1, [2] as P2, [3] as P3 from (
  select StudentID, ParentID, RANK() over (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY ParentID) as rnk
  from STUDENT_PARENTS
) ranked PIVOT (min(ParentID) for rnk in ([1], [2], [3])) as p
```

See it on SqlFiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3254/9

If you are using GUIDs it's a little more tricky, you need to cast them to BINARY to use min():

```
select StudentID, 
    cast([1] as uniqueidentifier) as P1, 
    cast([2] as uniqueidentifier) as P2, 
    cast([3] as uniqueidentifier) as P3 
from (
  select StudentID, cast(ParentID as binary(16)) as ParentID, RANK() over (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentParentID) as rnk
  from STUDENT_PARENTS
) ranked PIVOT (min(ParentID) for rnk in ([1], [2], [3])) as p
```

SqlFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d0d7/14

Comment: I am working with GUIDs (I used integers to make it easier to explain - sorry) and I'm getting an error around min()... is there another operator I could use?

Comment: See my update, you can cast uniqueidentifier to binary to get around the min problem

Comment: Note that even though I only switched ParentID over to uniqueidentifier in the SqlFiddle, you should be able to change the other columns to uniqueidentifier as well.

Comment: That worked perfectly... thanks again, I've been wracking my brain for a couple of hours.